# Add htaccess rules with insert_with_markers at beginning of htaccess

Tags: php, plugin-development, htaccess

From my custom plugin, on activation, i want add some rules into htaccess but at beginning of the file.

[insert_with_markers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/insert_with_markers/) add the rule at the end of htaccess, eg.:

```
$lines = array();
$lines[] = '# MY RULES';
return insert_with_markers(ABSPATH . '.htaccess', 'TEST', $lines);
```

result

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN TEST
# MY RULES
# END TEST
```

expected

```
# BEGIN TEST
# MY RULES
# END TEST
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

how add my rules at beginning of htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `insert_with_markers()` function you can insert your rules only between WordPress comments e.i. `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`.

So, you should use plain PHP to achieve your aim.

1. Create your rules
2. Read existing `.htaccess` and concatenate your and existing rules
3. Write the file

Here is a dirty example:

```
<?php
$str  = "# BEGIN  TEST\n# MY RULES\n# END TEST\n";
$str .= file_get_contents( ABSPATH . '.htaccess' );
file_put_contents( ABSPATH . '.htaccess', $str );
```

Or use `FILE_APPEND` flag with the `file_put_contents()`.

### Remember!

It's a very bad idea to allow PHP to alter your `.htaccess`. One infected file is enough to break your server.